# how to Extract mobile number from string using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pattern = @"1\d{10}"; // 匹配中国大陆手机号，以1开头，共11位
    string input = "Here is a phone number: 13812345678 and a bank card number: 15515615715815916016116216316416516616716816917017117217317417517617717817918018118218318418518618718818919019119219319419519619719819920020120220320420520620720820921021121221321421521621721821922022122222322422522622722822923023";

    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("phone number is: " + match.Value);
    }


    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

result:

```
phone number is: 13812345678
phone number is: 15515615715
phone number is: 15916016116
phone number is: 16316416516
phone number is: 16716816917
phone number is: 17117217317
phone number is: 17517617717
phone number is: 17918018118
phone number is: 18318418518
phone number is: 18718818919
phone number is: 19119219319
phone number is: 19519619719
phone number is: 19920020120
phone number is: 10211212213
phone number is: 14215216217
phone number is: 18219220221
```

but the problem: only 13812345678 is phone number,others are not , how to resolve? thx.

Comment: Is the input string always in this format? How long can the bank card number be? From wich country are the phone numbers (there are differences in length for different countrys)?

Comment: maybe this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zf5lVh - so expand your regex with `[^\d]` meaning after 10 digits there needs to be a non digit character or `([^\d]|$)` either non digit or end of string https://dotnetfiddle.net/SZwIR2

Comment: It's always a good idea to memorize one's bank card number in case it gets lost or stolen.

Comment: thanks brothers，Is the input string always in this format？ no,just a sample, but in fact , a long string can contains many digital combination ,such as  1392220202021233 ,1902223233 but its not chinese phone number.

Comment: Do chinese phone numbers always contain 11 digits and begin with 1 (as @AdrianHHH has assumed)?

Comment: yes , only 11 digits  and  begin with 1,other 10 digits not limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `pattern` as below should extract only 11 digit numbers starting with a `1`.

```
string pattern = @"\b1\d{10}\b";
```

The addition of the two `\b` requires a word boundary before and after the wanted number.

Comment: `\b` knew there was something like this, but couldn't think about it at top of my head, thats why I proposed `([^\d]|$)` in comments. :)